# jquery serializeArray values & write results in textarea

Tags: jquery, forms, serializearray

I'm having a little issue which I can't seem to get my head around. I am attempting to use **jQuery's .serialiseArray** function to combine a number of inputs & textarea values into single textarea for when the form is submitted.

I have created the following JS Fiddle to highlight my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/4XjhB/2/

As you will see, *I have been able to combine the values into the array, but I cannot seem to have the array write each value **on a new line** in the textarea*. It only writes the last input.

I have also included a div to show that it is working outside of a textarea

Please let me know where I am going wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should collect all values, when you call .val() it replaces value of textarea, but not appending it;
http://jsfiddle.net/4XjhB/3/

Comment: Actually, really quick question. Is there an easy way to tell the array to also pick up 'checked' checkboxes?. I've added a few in this if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/4XjhB/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4XjhB/5/ , actually serializeArray method works better with forms on it :) Or in you case add zinput class to chackboxes. http://jsfiddle.net/4XjhB/6/ or do it all from one submit event :)

Comment: Well it will be within a form but I'm looking to only combine certain inputs, hense the `.zinput` class. I suppose I can just write a function to add `.zinput` when the checkbox gets checked